# Want to pass non-alphabetic characters to an array in C but getting a segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I really appreciate any help/advice provided! Am noob.

This program is supposed to take text and cipher it using a key the user inputs. So when the user runs the program with their 26 letter key, the program asks them for plaintext (Whatever they want ciphered), then the program should output the ciphered text. I left out the validation & append functions in this question.

=====

My question is, in the for loop, alphabetic letters work fine. The issue is when there are NON-ALPHABETIC chars, the program returns a segmentation fault.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, or how I can fix this? In the meantime I will try ctype.h's "ispunc" "isspace" etc etc. Just wondering if there is a BASIC other way to do it that is shorter than typing that all out...we haven't learned pointers yet.

Let me know if any further info is needed...

```
// test key: ./substitution JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ
// test 2: ./substitution VcHpRzGjNtLsKfBdQwAxEuYmOi
// test 3: ./substitution vchprzgjntlskfbdqwaxeuymoi

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int validatekey(int argc, string argv[]);
void append(char* s, char c);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) // argc = # of command line args (name of program & input), argv saves them both.
{
    if (validatekey(argc, argv) == 0) //everything is fine
    {
        string key = argv[1]; //user's inputted key
        int keylength = strlen(key);
        string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
        string plainkey = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int plength = strlen(plaintext);
        char cipher[plength]; //outputted ciphertext

        for (int i = 0; i < plength; i++)
        {
            char p = tolower(plaintext[i]); //make plaintext lowercase so things match up
            char *where_is_p = strchr(plainkey, p);
            int index = (int)(where_is_p - plainkey); // get index of letter in plainkey
            char c = key[index]; //corresponding cipher index location
            
            if (isalpha(plaintext[i])) // check if letter is ALPHABET first
            {
                if (isupper(plaintext[i])) // if current plaintext char is uppercase
                {
                    //append(cipher, toupper(c));
                    printf("is upper");
                }
                else if (islower(plaintext[i])) // if it's lowercase
                {
                    //append(cipher, tolower(c));
                    printf("is lower");
                }
            }
            else //(isalpha(plaintext[i]) == 0 ) // if it's not a-z   NOTE: SEGMENTATION FAULT
            {
                //append(cipher, plaintext[i]);
                printf("not alpha");
            }
        }

        //printf("ciphertext: %s\n", cipher);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just changed the else part to: `else if ((isspace(plaintext[i])) || (isdigit(plaintext[i])) || (ispunct(plaintext[i]))  ) ` and am still getting a segmentation fault ;___;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, in the for loop, alphabetic letters work fine. The issue is when there are NON-ALPHABETIC chars, the program returns a segmentation fault.
> Does anyone have any idea why this happens,

`strchr(plainkey, p);` returns `NULL` when `p` not found in `plainkey`.  Code below dies on pointer subtraction and out of range array index.

```
char *where_is_p = strchr(plainkey, p);
int index = (int)(where_is_p - plainkey);
char c = key[index];
```

> or how I can fix this?

When `where_is_p == NULL`, perform the is-not-alpha code.

---

BTW, `char cipher[plength];` is 1 too small to form a *string* of ciphered text.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
It would have taken me an extremely long time to discover these bugs...will try putting the NULL piece in an if function and see if it works...will report back

Comment: @mrspoopybutthole Tip: save time, enable all warnings.  You can quickly catch a  lot of weak/faulty code that way.

Comment: ALSO- why is `char cipher[plength];` 1 too small for a string? Sorry for many questions

Comment: @mrspoopybutthole How big an array do you need to store the [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Definitions) `"abc"`? 3, 4, or what?

Comment: 3? Because 0 = a, 1 = b, 2 = c, 3= /0?



ALSO!!! IT WORKS! Thanks so much again. I moved the strchr part into the isalpha chunk so now it doesn't affect the nonalphabetic characters. Also did plength + 1

Comment: @mrspoopybutthole Code does index from 0 to 3, but that needs a **4** byte allocation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217570/discussion-between-mrspoopybutthole-and-chux-reinstate-monica).